# TypeError: _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function TypeError: _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-animations

here i tried to add fade up animation to the element

of home.component.html. But error occured. This is done on Angular 6. Thanks in advance.

Error occured after i added the animation :[.... ] section in home.component.ts

//app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
   ]
```

//home.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'dhz-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger( 'fadeInOnLoad', [
            state('unloaded', style({
                transform: 'translateY(-200px)',
                visibility: 'hidden',
                transition: '.5s transform .2s visibility',
            })),
            state('loaded', style({
                visibility: 'visible',
                transform: 'translateY(0)'
            })),
            transition('unloaded => loaded',[
                animate('2s')
            ]),


        ])
    ]
})
```

//home.component.html

```
<p [@fadeInOnLoad]="isLoaded ? loaded : unloaded" >Fade Up</p>
```

[Error Link Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP73R.jpg)

Comment: We are not magicians, post some useful code so we can help you out.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Sorry about that sir. I added Image now. Please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask read this first, then edit your question

Comment: The community here has no clue what your angular-animations-library is. Think about how we might could answer your question and provide more information. Not only screenshots with import links and an error.